# Each cyclic $R$-module is isomorphic to an $R$-module of the form $R/J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit.

I want to show that each cyclic $R$-module is isomorphic to an $R$-module of the form $R/J$ where $J$ is an ideal of $R$.

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we could show that?

Comment: Hint: Consider the annihilator of the module.

Comment: The annihilator of the module is $\text{Ann}_R(J)=\{r\in R\mid \forall j\in J, rj=0\}$, right? How could we use that? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Further hint: Consider a generator of the module and the map from the ring to the module sending $1$ to that generator.

Comment: Let $M$ be the cyclic $R$-module, that is generated by the elements $m$. We consider the mapping $\phi : R\rightarrow M$ with $1\mapsto m$. Do we have to show that this mapping is an homomorphism and bijective? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: No, you work a bit more with it and also think about the other hint.

Answer (score 5):

If $I$ is any ideal of $R$, then the quotient $R/I$ is not only a ring, but also an $R$-module, with scalar multiplication given by the formula $r \cdot (x+I) = rx+I$.

Let $M$ be a cyclic $R$-module.  So there exists an $m \in M$ such that $M = \{rm : r \in R\}$.  The function $\varphi: R \rightarrow M$ defined by $$\varphi(r) = rm$$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules.  What's the kernel?  How can we make use of this kernel?

Comment: Why is $R/I$ an $R$-module?

Comment: An $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ with respect to addition, together with a scalar multiplication function $R \times M \rightarrow M$ satisfying a list of axioms, right?

Comment: Already $R/I$ is an abelian group with respect to addition, and I just described the scalar multiplication function.  So you can check that it is in fact an $R$-module.

Comment: Ah ok... Why is the scalar multiplication given by the formula $r\cdot (x+I)=rx+I$ ?

Comment: I don't know lol, that is just how the formula is defined, and when people say "$R/I$ is an $R$-module," that is what they mean.  I cannot think of any other natural way to define a function $R \times R/I \rightarrow R/I$ which together with addition makes $R/I$ into an $R$-module.  Can you?

Comment: Ah ok... To show that the mapping is an homomorphism we do the following, right? $$\phi (a+b)=(a+b)m=am+bm=\phi (a)+\phi (b) \\ \phi (na)=nam=n\phi (a)$$ The kernel is $\ker \phi =\{r\in R\mid rm=0\}$. How can we show that this is equal to the ideal?

Comment: The kernel $\mathfrak a := \textrm{ker } \phi$ IS an ideal of $R$.  Now define a new function $\overline{\phi}: R/\mathfrak a \rightarrow M$ by the formula $$\overline{\phi}(r+\mathfrak a) := \phi(r) = rm$$ Show that it is well defined, an $R$-module homomorphism, and a bijection.  Thus $M$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $R$ by an ideal.

Comment: And yes that's right, that's how you show that $\phi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism.

Comment: Why do we have to define that new function? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Well you want an isomorphism between $M$ and $R$ modulo some ideal, right?  So ultimately you need to construct such a function.

Comment: But why do we have to define the function $\overline{\phi}$ and not use the function $\phi$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39832/discussion-between-d-s-and-mary-star).

Comment: I get $M=\{km|\ k\in Z\}$ as M is a cyclic abelian group with additive notation here, but I don't get why $M=\{rm|\ r\in R\}$ necessarily? It can be an R-module but still $\{rm|\ r\in R\} \subsetneq M$ ? Or should we prove it from the axioms?

Comment: Instead of reproving first isomorphism theorem for module, just quote it.